# deploying in jetty giving Java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WIRE_BUS_NAME

Tags: spring, apache, jetty, cxf

I am getting bellow error while deploying a service in jetty. I am not sure if it is happening because of any cxf dependency miss or any spring dependency mismatch. Earlier I resolved this problem by upgrading hibernate3 to hibernate 5.0.1.RELEASE. But this time there is no hibernate in my project nor it is getting injected from any parent dependency. Please help me with this!

```
 Unable to reach node goal: started
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WIRE_BUS_NAME
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:111)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:282)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:177)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:890)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:853)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1514)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1476)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:502)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:447)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:239)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:449)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:416)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1584)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1508)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1507)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:506)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:78)
```

Below are some versions I am using in my project :

```
<cxf.version>3.2.1</cxf.version>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<jaxb.version>2.2.5</jaxb.version>
<log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
<maven.resource.plugin.version>3.0.2</maven.resource.plugin.version>
<maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.7.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
<maven-release-plugin.version>2.5.3</maven-release-plugin.version>
                                                                              <springframework.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
<spring-ws.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring-ws.version>
<sl4j.version>1.6.6</sl4j.version>
<servlet-api.version>2.4</servlet-api.version>
<sourceforge.version>1.2.5</sourceforge.version>
<wsdl4j.version>1.6.3</wsdl4j.version>
```

I have below cxf plugin in my project :

```
              <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                    <dependencies>

                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                            <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                            <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                           <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                           <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                           <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
                        </dependency>   

                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: The whole stacktrace is important here.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Could you please check now?

Comment: Gut says you have mixed versions of the CXF jars in your `WEB-INF/lib`.   Can you build your war and then do a directory listing of just the `WEB-INF/lib`.  Look for multiple CXF jars, especially at different versions.